# How to toggle the form height?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one form and a button inside it, how can i toggle the window height, so when i click on the button for the first time, the window height will increase by 166, and when i click on the button for the second time, the height will be decreased by 166.

Sorry for the question being stupid but i got really confused ;thanks

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int  FormHeight = this.Height;
        int  FormHeightBefore = FormHeight;

        if (this.Height == FormHeightBefore)
        {//toggle off 
            this.Height = this.Height + 166;
        }
        else { 
        //toggle on
            this.Height = this.Height - 166;
        }

    }
```

I tried with the code above but the it doesn't worked, Whenever i press the button, the form height still increasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partial class Form1 {
    public int FormHeight;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Height += (FormHeight = (FormHeight > 0 ? -1 : 1) * 166);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it changes itself, but I agree that it's not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

Notice your first 2 lines:

```
int  FormHeight = this.Height;
int  FormHeightBefore = FormHeight;
```

You're actually *always* setting both variables to the **current** height...

So the same if statement is always called...

This will work correctly:

```
const int heightOffset = 166;
int  FormHeightBefore = this.Height
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Height == FormHeightBefore)
    {//toggle off 
        this.Height += heightOffset ;
    }
    else
    { 
       //toggle on
        this.Height = FormHeightBefore;
    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot the ; at the end of first line... Besides, it's not so elegant to use the "magic" number 166 twice.

Comment: Why don't use the number 166 twice ?c @OferZelig

Comment: There was no point to edit, I've already wrote the right full answer...

@ShikataGaNai - because when you come back to change the number, you might forget one of them.

Comment: @ShikataGaNai - I'm guessing he's talking about using a constant instead of just writing `166`.  Notice I used the `heightOffset` constant. This is better since it allows you to easily change this value in the future (instead of searching the entre code for 166)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
bool isExpanded;

private void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Height += (isExpanded ? -166 : 166);

    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because every time you enter the method (via button's click), it checks for the *current* form height and considers it to be the "initial one".

Do something like:

```
private readonly int initialHeight;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initialHeight = this.Height;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.Height == initialHeight)
    {   // increase height
        this.Height = initialHeight + 166;
    }
    else { 
        // decrease height
        this.Height = initialHeight;
    }
}
```

Note that the initial `initialHeight` declaration is *outside* the scope of your button's click event.

Comment: A constant would be better then just "166"

Comment: Don't agree, depends on the actual use. If it's used in only one place and there's no special logical meaning for that (that is - it does not represent a meaningful constant that is worth describing in English), then it's OK.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, "the word this doesn't exist in the current context" @OferZelig